# R filter dataframe if some columns contain string

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

This may seem rather trivial, but I barely don't know any R at all and google-fu didn't help.

So, scenario is as follows:
I have a dataframe with 37 columns, and I need to filter it, keeping only those rows that contain a certain string in any of 2 columns (EMPRESA, PAIS).

What I've tried so far:

```
        if(input$ExperienciasSearchHidden == "")
        {
        }
        else
        {
            print(colnames(DFfilters))
            DFfilters <- DFfilters  [which  (
                                                    DFfilters$EMPRESA       ==  "ESPAÑAAA"
                                                &   DFfilters$PAIS          ==  "ESPAÑAAA"
                                            )
                                    ,]
        }
```

Output (ERROR):

```
Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  [No stack trace available]
```

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: NOTE: I'm using the operator == and a hardcoded value to simplify as much my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the second part of the code with the subsetting but the problem is in the if statement. It is likely that `input$ExperienciasSearchHidden` is NA.

```
DFfilters=data.frame(EMPRESA=c("a", "ESPAÑAAA", "b"), PAIS=c(NA,"ESPAÑAAA", "a"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DFfilters  [which  (
  DFfilters$EMPRESA       ==  "ESPAÑAAA"
  &   DFfilters$PAIS          ==  "ESPAÑAAA"
)
,]
   EMPRESA     PAIS
2 ESPAÑAAA ESPAÑAAA

NA==""
NA

if (NA) {
  print("problem")
}
Error in if (NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: I'm a complete noob at R, but I don't think that's the problem, cuse I ```  print(paste('ExperienciasSearchHidden=' , toString(input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) , sep=""))``` and it prints a string :S

Comment: Is the string that it prints ‘ExperienciasSearchHiddenNA’? How about class(input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) and what does it say. Try toString(input$ExperienciasSearchHidden) inside the if statement, you can only compare strings to “”

Comment: It seems that the Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed camed a couple lines below my if-else, on an operation not ready to accept an empty dataframe. I'll gladly accept @Stacker answer and post a new one, since I'm not able to filter the dataframe properly :'(

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of reproducible data, here's a solution with mock data:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(any(str_detect(c_across(), 'EMPRESA|PAIS')))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  v1      v1.1   
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 x       PAIS   
2 EMPRESA x      
3 x       EMPRESA
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c("x", "EMPRESA", "y", "z", "x"),
  v1 = c("PAIS", "x", "y", "z", "EMPRESA")
)
```